# Find more method to analysis a group of data to choose a better decision

Tags: statistics

I need to choose one from several decision, for each choice I know the frequency of the random variable $X=1,2,3,4,5$ via the random experiment. And I hope the $X$ to be as small as possible.

I only know the mean value and variance can be used to choose. What other method/statistics can I use to make a best decision? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hope to be small *on average*?

Comment: Yes, and hope the large value as few as possible.

Comment: "As few as possible" is imprecise.  You must write a mathematical "cost function" stating precisely what is the optimal set of outcomes.  So which is better, $6$ $1$s and $9$ $10$s OR $4$ $1$s, $6$ $2$s, and $5$ $8$s?  See your problem?  Nobody can help you unless you write a FORMULA for the cost function.